# Изменение переменной которая использовалась для помещения элемент в стек меняет сам элемент стека

Tags: delphi, lazarus, стек

Программа написана в IDE lazarus 1.6.
Есть класс с таким объявлением:

```
DataForm = class
    public
        Choices:longint;
        BackUp:boolean;
    private
        nameForm:String;
        operationForm:TypeOperation;
    public
        function getForm():String;
        procedure setForm(const nForm:String);
        function getOperation():TypeOperation;
        procedure setOperation(const oForm:TypeOperation);
end;
```

И таким описанием:

```
function DataForm.getForm():String;
begin
     getForm:=nameForm;
end;
procedure DataForm.setForm(const nForm : String);
begin
     nameForm:=nForm;
end;

function DataForm.getOperation():TypeOperation;
begin
     getOperation:=operationForm;
end;

procedure DataForm.setOperation(const oForm:TypeOperation);
begin
     operationForm:=oForm;
end;
```

Для работы со стеком из класса таких объектов используется `uses gstack;`

```
type     iStack = specialize TStack<DataForm>;  
 var TopForm: iStack;   
 CurrentStatus:DataForm;
```

В форма по нажатию на кнопку выполняется такой код:

```
   TopForm.CleanupInstance;
   CurrentStatus.setForm('fRoot');
   CurrentStatus.setOperation(oRoot);
   TopForm.Push(CurrentStatus);

   CurrentStatus.setForm('fViewPatientStory');
   CurrentStatus.setOperation(View);
   TopForm.Push(CurrentStatus);

   CurrentStatus.setForm('fViewPatient');
   CurrentStatus.setOperation(View);
   ShowMessage(TopForm.Top().getForm());

   TopForm.Pop;
   ShowMessage(TopForm.Top().getForm());
```

Выдается 2 сообщения: fViewPatient.
Мне нужно чтобы элементы помещенные в стек оставались с теми же значениями с которыми они были в момент помещения, а так получается, что любой элемент стека ссылается на переменную CurrentStatus и при ее изменении меняются все значения элементов стека. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Так и не добавляйте `ссылку` на тот же самый объект в стек. Создавайте *новый* объект и его помещайте туда.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CurrentStatus := DataForm.Create;
CurrentStatus.setForm('fRoot');
CurrentStatus.setOperation(oRoot);
TopForm.Push(CurrentStatus);

CurrentStatus := DataForm.Create;
CurrentStatus.setForm('fViewPatientStory');
CurrentStatus.setOperation(View);
TopForm.Push(CurrentStatus);

CurrentStatus := DataForm.Create;
CurrentStatus.setForm('fViewPatient');
CurrentStatus.setOperation(View);
ShowMessage(TopForm.Top().getForm());

TopForm.Pop;
ShowMessage(TopForm.Top().getForm());
```

И не забудьте освободить память, выделенную под три CurrentStatus, если сам TStack этого не делает

Comment: Это то, что мне нужно. Спасибо за помощь. .